# Can't create SQL table using phphmyadmin UI

Tags: phpmyadmin

so today I wanted to start working on a mini project in my spare time from work. I opend PHPMyAdmin and created a new DB, when I click on create new table I enter a name and select the number of columns, the problem is it does nothing, I can have 7 columns but it only shows one and when I hit GO it does nothing. Creating the table with a query works but I find int strange it does not work with the UI, has anyone ever faced this?

[image: Only one row appers]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I noticed that the I'm missing the preview SQL button aswell.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, you have to enter a max character limit in the length/values section.

Comment: Thats not the problem, I can't add any new collum , so my table is stuck at only 1 collum

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn’t read the question correctly but it’s probably just a glitch or something. Try to reload the page or try again some other time.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the issue by instaling xamppp again.